# How to compress or convert to low quality MP3 file from PHP

Tags: php, mp3

Is there any PHP library or function to convert MP3 files to lower quality?

I want to compress/convert 128Kbps or higher quality MP3 files to 64Kbps MP3 files by PHP.

Does anyone know?

Comment: +1 because its a php question and didnt involve the word 'ajax' or 'jquery' lol

Comment: PHP stands for **HTML** preprocessor. There is no "mp3" or "music editor" in it. And no "coffee machine" or "space shuttle" either.

Comment: PHP have a GD library to process images file, and ffmpeg library to process movie file. Why not have no library to process mp3 file? I successful to process mp3`s id3 stuffs using PHP. I think there will have some relative library to do this thing, right?

Comment: take the Unix approach and just all another process to handle it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, you need to install ffmpeg available at:
http://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Then, make sure you have **safe mode** enabled in your PHP configuration and select the right dir where you can execute files:
**safe_mode_exec_dir**

Finally, use:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp3 -ab 64 outputfile.mp3")
```

Comment: Ok,thank you your answer. It works! But additionally, it have to set 64 as 64000.

Comment: On Linux/Ubuntu, just install it through `apt install ffmpeg`

Answer (score 4):

Have you taken a look at ffmpeg? http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

This command worked for me

```
exec("ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp3 -b:a 64k outputfile.mp3")
```

Answer (score 2):

keep in mind php can easily execute shell commands or scripts, so calling external programs opens many possibilities.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php

Answer (score 1):

To my way of thinking, to compress a mp3 music file, means reducing the weight in MB. You make the mp3 portable so that you can email it. You can half the MB by converting it from stereo to mono, you throw one sound track away. On the small speakers of my desktop PC computer I honesty can not hear the difference between a (4 MB) 128 kbps stereo mp3 and a (1 MB) 32 kbps mono mp3 music file. So, if you really want to compress a mp3 music file, I would suggest the following ffmpeg, where –ac 1 means one audio channel (mono). 
exec("ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp3 –ab 32k –ac 1 outputfile.mp3")

I noticed that my comment was voted down. Not without reason. What I forgot to say, is that a 16 kbps mono MP3 sounds a lot better than a 16 kbps stereo. Maybe you don’t compress the MP3 by converting it from stereo to mono, but you maintain better sound quality, allowing you to compress the MP3 further. I did this for years when I still had dial-up internet, I had to, to enable me to email an MP3. Sorry for the oversight, I simply forgot ... it was years ago.