# ffmpeg compresses upto 32 kbps only

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have created a PHP code which compresses mp3 while uploaded to 32kbps bit rate I have referred this thread

[How to compress or convert to low quality Mp3 file from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628221/how-to-compress-or-convert-to-low-quality-mp3-file-from-php)

used this code

```
exec("ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp3 -ab 24000 outputfile.mp3")
```

but the problem is I can't compress more than 32kbps .my code instruct to compress up to 24kbps but after execution, I can see the output file is 32kbps. can anyone tell what should I do so that I can compress more than 32kbps .or is there any limitation of ffmpeg ??

Comment: it would have been better ate SuperUser site, because this has nothing to do with php. Its about setting correct flags for `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reason you cant achieve lower then 32kbps is because of the sample rate most likely is still 44100-Hz meaning larger stream size, you have a few options `44100-Hz, 22050-Hz, and 11025-Hz` as valid frequency's.

Try (very low quality):

`ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp3 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 8k -ac 1 -ar 11025 outputfile.mp3`

-b:a = audio bitrate

-ar  = sample rate

Comment: I think these are the [supported sample rates of libmp3lame](https://sourceforge.net/p/lame/svn/6429/tree/trunk/lame/libmp3lame/util.c#l419). 8000, 11025, ..., 48000. I guess these are just the [rates supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#Bit_rate) by the spec.