# How to compress mp3 file in php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, laravel-5

I am doing a php project. In my project, I need to compress mp3 files to reduce the file size because I need to store a lot of mp3 files.

How can I compress it in php? I am using `laravel` framework. If possible, I want it without extra installation. I already checked `ffmpeg`, but I was not able to use it due to the poor documentation. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer Already posted** in the respective links of stackoverflow
[how-to-compress-or-convert-to-low-quality-mp3-file-from-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628221/how-to-compress-or-convert-to-low-quality-mp3-file-from-php)

While **using zip command line** with PHP to add a folder into an archive file:

General command:

```
zip archive.zip file.mp3
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php $path2mp3 = '../Downloads/Medias/MP3/001.mp3';$site = 'site.com';$compressFolder = $site.'.zip';$cmd = "zip -r $compressFolder $path2mp3"; $compressMP3 = exec($cmd ." 2>&1" );echo $compressMP3;if($compressMP3){echo 'Done';}else{echo 'Not Done';}?>
```

Comment: I already browsed that link . My apache throwing error when I enable safe mode . That is why I want minimum installation .

Comment: **use** zip command line with PHP to add a folder into an archive file. need code for zip archive.?

Comment: Yes please . I surely need it .

Comment: what value I must provide for $site variable ? I just want to store in local project .

Comment: just use your folder name you want to store

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Audio compress
    $inputAudio = public_path('/audio/myaudio.mp3');
    $outputAudio = public_path('/output/outputAudio.mp3');
    exec("ffmpeg -i $inputAudio -ab 64 $outputAudio");

    // Video compress
    $inputVideo = public_path('/audio/myvideo.mp4');
    $outputVideo = public_path('/output/outputVideo.mp4');
    exec("ffmpeg -i $inputVideo -vf scale=1280:-1 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 24 $outputVideo");
```